# Core data memory management

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, swift3

I use core data to store data, in this i have some memory issues

I add data to entity by multithreading, this process increases the memory

```
    var i = 0
    for i in i..<100
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            Localmanager().adddata() 
        }}

func adddatan()
{
    let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)


    childContext.parent = CoreDataStore.managedObjectContext



    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Dashboard", in: childContext)

    var i = 0
    var n = 100

    if(thre % 2 == 0)
    {
        n = 500
    }

    for i in i..<n
    {


        let dashboart = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,insertInto: childContext)

        dashboart.setValue(22, forKeyPath: "count")
        dashboart.setValue("ramu", forKeyPath: "createdby")
        dashboart.setValue(thre, forKeyPath: "id")
        dashboart.setValue("Dashbord1", forKeyPath: "name")
        dashboart.setValue([123,124,125], forKeyPath: "rids")
        dashboart.setValue(true, forKeyPath: "fav")

    }

    do {
        try childContext.save()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")

    }




}
```

and then I deleted the object from context but it does not reduce the memory

```
func cleandata() {


    do {
        let managedOC = CoreDataStore.managedObjectContext


        var a = try managedOC!.fetch(Dashboard.fetchRequest()) //gives array of dashboard entity object

        for obje in a
        {

            CoreDataStore.managedObjectContext?.delete(obje as! NSManagedObject)
        }
                }
    catch

    {
        print("error clean")
    }


}
```

Some fetch, save operation done by background thread after the instance end the memory not free. how to free memory?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfJGv.png)

Comment: first thing go for batch saving & deleting option.

Comment: Standard knee-jerk answer: unless you believe that Core Data doesn't respond properly to low-memory warnings, it growing its cache isn't generally considered problematic. There's no value in having RAM that isn't in use given that there's a system for reclaiming allocated memory. In the simulator, try simulating a low memory warning and see what happens. Also presumably you're already sure that you're not accidentally holding on to the allocated object elsewhere?